# Looking for undergraduate degree in Maths through distance learning

Tags: undergraduate-education

Do you know of any Universities offering an undergraduate degree in Maths by distance learning other than the Open University.It is important that the content is in English language and any tutors will be able to deliver any online tutorial in English.

Comment: FWIW, I’ve created some automated tutorials for mathematics: http://www.public-domain-materials.com/folder-student-exercise-tasks-for-mathematics-language-arts-etc---autocorrected.html

Comment: You should be aware that, to the best of my knowledge (as an interested party), the available on-line programs (in early 2016) are not very good at all, and will often not be recognized as truly legitimate, whether or not they have some legal status. Second, again with qualifications, the perspective such programs will give an aspiring mathematician is fatally limited in ways that a naive person would not see. I myself do entirely endorse the idea of more-freely available information via internet, but the situation is still flawed... despite YouTube, whatever. It's not mature. Duh, ... :)

Comment: @paul garrett It is unfortunate indeed. I wonder, which university will be the first to offer a serious math major online. I've not seen a program which seems up to the standards I see in many residential programs...

Answer (score 2):

You could look at [Massey University](http://www.engine.ac.nz/aperfectexample/locations/distance-learning/).
I have known many people to use this university's distance program, undergrad and postgrad, and they have had good experiences. It was even recommended by my local university as the best option for a non-contact course.

Below are the available Maths/Stats distance papers this year - enough for a full degree.

160.101 Calculus I
160.102 Linear Mathematics
160.103 Introductory University Mathematics
160.111 Mathematics 1A
160.112 Mathematics 1B
160.203 Calculus
160.204 Differential Equations I
160.211 Linear Algebra
160.212 Discrete Mathematics
160.301 Analysis
160.314 Combinatorics
160.318 Differential Equations II
160.320 Mathematics in Education

161.120 Introductory Statistics
161.130 Introductory Biostatistics
161.200 Statistical Models
161.220 Data Analysis
161.221 Applied Linear Models
161.223 Introduction to Data Mining
161.304 Advanced Statistical Modelling
161.322 Design and Analysis of Surveys and Experiments
161.327 Generalised Linear Models
161.342 Forecasting and Time Series
161.380 Statistical Analysis Project

Answer (score 1):

Western Governors University. One of my coworkers has a masters from them, and our school is also currently hosting a student teacher who is getting his undergrad through them.